# Connect to internet from a linux system via ISA proxy

Tags: proxy, wget

I've an Oracle Linux server. I want to connect to internet from that machine- like wget, yum, etc. but my network proxy is a Windows one (ISA server) with authentication. What configurations to be done?

I tried adding the following line to /etc/wgetrc

http_proxy=http://mywindowsdomain\mywindowsuser:mywindowspassword@xxx.mydomain.com:8080/

But it's not working. when I try wget http://google.com/ following error is shown:

Resolving xxx.mydomain.com... 192.168.10.35
Connecting to xxx.mydomain.com|192.168.10.35|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
2016-12-06 10:41:48 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ).

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The 407 error implies that your proxy doesn't accept basic authentication. 
Try using http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ to pass your credentials and then connect to cntlm on a loopback address

For example:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```